# Problem with job queue in python telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telegram-api

```
y=str("12:50AM")+"+0000"
bot_refresh_time = datetime.strptime(y,'%I:%M%p%z').timetz()
bot_refresh_time=bot_refresh_time.replace(tzinfo = tz)
updater.job_queue.run_once(bot_bal,bot_refresh_time,name="daily_check_task")
```

The code above executes with out an error, its added to job queue but callback is not called.

while if i change *run_once* to *run_daily*, it works perfectly fine
ie`updater.job_queue.run_daily(bot_bal,bot_refresh_time,name="daily_check_task")`

**or**

if the time zone is "None"(tzinfo=None) in above code then, *run_once* work perfectly fine, so i thought the problem is with time zone, but if that's the case then *run_daily* shouldn't work because they both use *datetime.time* for time in syntax

syntax for job queue [run_once](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.jobqueue.html#telegram.ext.JobQueue.run_once) for python telegram bot.

syntax for job queue [run_daily](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.jobqueue.html#telegram.ext.JobQueue.run_daily) for python telegram bot.

**Any suggestions or answers would be helpful. i'm just beginner in coding :)**

**EDIT:**
*run_once* works but instead of setting the given time as the timezone(`bot_refresh_time=bot_refresh_time.replace(tzinfo = tz)`), it converts the time to the given timezone (ie if my timezone is Asia/Kolkata and the given time is 01:00AM, while using using *run_once* the job executes at 06:30AM IST instead of 01:00AM IST). This problem only occurs when using *run_once*, there is no problem with *run_daily*

Answer (score 1):

As of version 13.0, `JobQueue` can only handle `pytz` timezones, as PTB uses the library APScheduler for the `JobQueue`. Note that older versions are no longer supported. A working example for `run_once` would be:

```
import datetime as dtm
import pytz

from telegram.ext import Updater

updater = Updater('TOKEN')


def test(_):
    print('running at', dtm.datetime.utcnow())


time = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata').localize(dtm.datetime.now() + dtm.timedelta(seconds=5))
updater.job_queue.run_once(test, time, name="daily_check_task")
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

Comment: Thank you! It is still an issue in version 13.5. Wrapping `pytz.timezone('<timezone>').localize( )` around my `datetime`-object fixed `run_once`! Btw. the timezones can be listed using `pytz.all_timezones`.